# Is there a way to format the text in HTML5 setCustomValidity?

Tags: javascript, css, html, forms

I'm implementing OWASP password requirements and I was hoping to use setCustomValidity on the password HTML Input element. However, the password requirements involve a lot of complicated steps that I will need to make the user aware of.

Is there any way to apply formatting, or even newlines, to the text that appears in setCustomValidity?

Comment: I've tried the usual stuff, `\n`, `&#xA;`, and `<br />`, and nothing has worked for me, so I'm interested in this answer, too.

Comment: I researched this more and this question received no attention. I ended up just setting a div via the usual position: relative -> position: absolute strategy.